# Show that every real number is a limit of rational number.

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that every real number is a limit of rational number.

I understand that the statement is true and very trivial. But how can I mathematically show that! Please help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\forall x\in\mathbb R,\quad x_n=\frac{\lfloor10^n x\rfloor}{10^n}\to x$$

Comment: Is $x_n$ rational?

Comment: Of course it's rational as quotient of two integers.